# Is there a way to test whether risk is the same for multiple groups?

Tags: regression

If you want to test whether 5 groups have the same risk or different risks for some bnary outcome variable is there any test you can perform? Something like an F-test or chi-squared test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chi-Squared test is a straightforward one and it sounds like exactly what you need for your situation, unless there are complications that you haven't described.  You'll find explanations in any introductory statistics text, on wikipedia, and elsewhere.  You may even find an online calculator you can use; it'll need to accomodate the "5x2" format of your data.

Comment: So is this basically similar to the F-Test in regression?